# Java Read How to read first word then the rest of an input

Tags: java, token, java.util.scanner, tokenize

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read the rest of a input line. I need to token the first word then possibly create the rest of the input line as one whole token

```
public Command getCommand() 
{
    String inputLine;   // will hold the full input line
    String word1 = null;
    String word2 = null;

    System.out.print("> ");     // print prompt

    inputLine = reader.nextLine();

    // Find up to two words on the line.
    Scanner tokenizer = new Scanner(inputLine);
    if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
        word1 = tokenizer.next();      // get first word
        if(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
            word2 = tokenizer.next();     // get second word
            // note: just ignores the rest of the input line.
        }
    }

    // Now check whether this word is known. If so, create a command
    // with it. If not, create a "null" command (for unknown command).
    if(commands.isCommand(word1)) {
        return new Command(word1, word2);
    }
    else {
        return new Command(null, word2); 
    }
}
```

The input:

```
take spinning wheel
```

Output:

```
spinning
```

Desired Output:

```
spinning wheel
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `split()`
`String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(" ");

String firstWord = line[0];

String secondWord = line[1];`

It means that you need to split the line at space and that will convert it into the array. Now using yhe index you can get any word you want

Answer (score 0):

OR -

```
String inputLine =//Your Read line
String desiredOutput=inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf(" ")+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also...

```
String s = "This is Testing Result";
System.out.println(s.split(" ")[0]);
System.out.println(s.substring(s.split(" ")[0].length()+1, s.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(String regex, int limit)`

```
String[] line = scan.nextLine().split(" ", 2);

String firstWord = line[0];

String rest= line[1];
```

Refer to [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) here